# IOS NSobject deep child filtering with NSpredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, subquery, nspredicate, nsobject

```
matsDataObject *notebook1 = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Notebook 1" children:nil];
matsDataObject *notebook2 = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Notebook 2" children:nil];

matsDataObject *computer1 = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Computer 1"
                                                      children:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notebook1, notebook2, nil]];
matsDataObject *computer2 = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Computer 2" children:nil];
matsDataObject *computer3 = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Computer 3" children:nil];

matsDataObject *computer = [matsDataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Computers"
                                                     children:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:computer1, computer2, computer3, nil]];
```

This is my NSobject :

Computers has name "Computers" and children "NSarray with values Computer 1, Computer 2 and Computer 3"

Computer 1 has name "Computer 1" and children "NSarray with values Notebook 1 and Notebook 2"

Trough NSpredicate I want to get the parent object "Computers" when I search for "Notebook 1"

What I tried :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(children, $child, $child.children.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0",searchText];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY children.children.name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
```

Comment: Try `ANY children.@distinctUnionOfArrays.children.name contains[cd] %@` or `SUBQUERY(children, $child, ANY $child.children.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0`.

Comment: Yes yes yes ! It works, thank you so much. Should have posted this question earlier, wasted 2 days on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question. The answer comes from Willeke.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY children.@distinctUnionOfArrays.children.name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
```